# Dismiss VC2 --> IBOutlets in VC1 = nil

Tags: ios

In VC1 I have a bunch of IBOutlets that display some data, one of them (UIButton) is hooked up to a segue(modal) in Storyboard that presents VC2, which animates by default from the bottom to top.  In VC2 I have a TV where I can add/delete the datapoints visualised in VC1. I also have a UIButton that takes me back to VC1. 
At first I just hooked it up to another modal segue.  That made the IBOutlets in VC1 update to any changes I made to the datapoints in VC2 - Great!  But I want the animation to happen in reverse(from top to bottom).. and so I tried this code:

```
@IBAction func dismissVC2(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, when I get back to VC1 all the IBOutlets that display data are nil and they are not updated...
How can I get from VC2 to VC1 with an animation from top to bottom and "refresh" VC1?

Comment: You aredoing something wrong. The IBOutlets should not be set to nil. Show some more code or explain where your outlets are nil...

Comment: Maybe nil is the wrong word.  The IBOutlets falls back to the "default" value (1234) I entered as a placeholder value in the StoryBoard.  Basically they no longer show the data they did before VC2.  I am not sure how else to explain it.  I think these questions are about the same issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732084/iboutlet-nil-after-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier

Comment: You need to use an unwind segue so that you can pass the data to VC1